# Initial entry requirement for Australia PR Visa

Tags: australia, residency, skilled-migration

I was granted Australian permanent residence visa (189) this March. It has an initial entry date for October 2016. I landed Australia in March this year and stayed for 3 days and exited Australia. I am planning to move to Australia permanently in January next year (which is well past my initial entry date of October).

As there are no other conditions on my visa, Am I fine with it? Do I have to be in Australia on the day of "first entry date"? Can anyone confirm me?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[Australia's Skilled Independent visa (subclass 189)](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/189-) is a permanent visa, allowing you to live, work in the country and, if you're eligible, eventually apply for citizenship.

As such, you can enter anytime on or after the date indicated, October 2016; the visa lasts indefinitely and any entry to Australia is sufficient for validation. You simply need to clear Immigration and passport control.